# Calculating total price php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum

Right now i have this piece of code running:

```
$count = 0;
    foreach ($products as $key => $product){
      $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';
            if (!$number){
            $count++;
            echo "";
            } else {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $product;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $number;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                $price = $prices[$count]* $number;
                echo "&#8364 ", $price;
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $count++;
        }
    }
```

But now i added a 3rd row (my first row is just the `<th>`'s) beneath that one looking like this:

```
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo "Totaal";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $totalproducts;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $totalprice;
    echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

As you can see i placed 2 $total... in this row where as you can guess need to come the total products ordered and total price of those products.

My problem is that i don't really know how to let it sum up all the $price and place this in $totalprice and sum up all $number and place it inside the $totalnumber. I know it's a basic question but it has been a long time ago since i actually worked with php. And i'm stuck on this.

I appreciate any help on this matter, thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you mean... $price=$price+$prices[$count]* $number;

Comment: @user1844933 Hmm, no i do not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope you want this

first set the variable `$total_products` and `$total_price`

```
$total_products = 0; // set to 0 initially
$total_price = 0; // set to 0 initially

    $count = 0;
        foreach ($products as $key => $product){
          $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';
                if (!$number){
                $count++;
                echo "";
                } else {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo $product;
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    echo $number;
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                    $price = $prices[$count]* $number;
                    echo "&#8364 ", $price;
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $total_products += 1; // update total_products +1
            $total_price += $price;  // update total_price +$price
            $count++;
            }
        }
```

and put them here like

```
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo "Totaal";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $total_products;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $total_price;
    echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: This was exactly what i needed only the `$total_products += 1;` needed to be `$total_products += $number;` since my product works the same as my price system, the user could for example order 3 products from that type and 5 from another type, making 8. But thanks so much for the help and effort!

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$totalprice=0;
$count = 0;
    foreach ($products as $key => $product){
      $number = isset($_POST[$key])?$_POST[$key]:'';
            if (!$number){
            $count++;
            echo "";
            } else {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $product;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $number;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                $price = $prices[$count]* $number;
                $totalprice = $totalprice+ $price;
                echo "&#8364 ", $price;
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $count++;
        }
    }
```

and

```
echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo "Totaal";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $total_products;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        echo $totalprice;
    echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```